# Need help in speeding up a looping macro

Tags: excel, vba, performance, loops

I am using a Macro to identify same details entered (in Column B, C and D) for multiple students (Column A).
This macro is working fine on approx 10,000 rows. But when I use it on full database ex: 1,00,000 rows it just got hanged.

Any help to in speeding up this macro will be very helpful.

`

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
  Dim lRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
  Dim c As Integer
  Dim students() As Variant
  Dim results() As Variant

  lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  ReDim results(lRow - 1)
  students = Range("A1:D" & lRow).Value
 
  For i = 2 To lRow
    found = False
    For j = 2 To lRow
      If students(i, 1) = students(j, 1) Then GoTo skipStudent
      For c = 1 To 4
        If students(j, c) = "-" Or students(i, c) = "-" Then GoTo skipColumn
        If students(i, c) = students(j, c) Then
          results(i - 1) = results(i - 1) & "Same " & students(1, c) & " information with " & students(j, 1) & vbCrLf
        End If
skipColumn:
        Next
skipStudent:
    Next
  Next
 
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  For i = 2 To lRow
    Cells(i, 5).Value = results(i - 1)
  Next
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

`

Comment: I don't get the full idea of your task, so hard to propose a better solution. However, on the first sight I think you can improve with `For j = i+1 to lRow` (if you checked row 2 against row 3, there is no need to check row 3 against row 2), and the inner loop can be reduced to `For c = 2 To 4`

Comment: I would consider the use of ".Offset(row, column)" to remove at least one of the inner loops.